# adding dates to slots if between two dates

Tags: excel, vba, calendar

I have a list of dates that each person (int) has requested off. I would like to write something that takes the array of dates and checks to see if it is between the two dates that go across the top of the picture.

so for int1 the 5 flex days would be placed within their appropriate week block in the second cell down from weekdays and the 5 vacation days which signal a whole week off would be placed in the first cell down from week days

then it cycles through the int#

[image]

I tried to do this by formula

```
=IF(OR(AND($I$82>=R78,$I$82<T78),AND($J$82>=R78,$J$82<T78),AND($K$82>=R78,$K$82<T78),AND($L$82>=R78,$L$82<T78),AND($M$82>=R78,$M$82<T78)),"vac"," ")
```

```
=IF(OR(AND($C$82>=R78,$C$82<T78),AND($D$82>=R78,$D$82<T78),AND($E$82>=R78,$E$82<T78),AND($F$82>=R78,$F$82<T78),AND($G$82>=R78,$G$82<T78)),"FLEX"," ")
```

but it gets messy when trying to drag it down to include all int#. in addition I would prefer the cells just have the text written in when the macro is run so that I can adjust the schedule afterwards